# Connect data to a google analytics session in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

On Google Analytics, in Javascript, is there a way to tie certain behavior to which session ID a user is on?

For example, every time the user changes GA sessions, we want to show the user a different version of the site.

It seems that GA doesn't really offer up the session ID.

We are tracking site versions via Google Analytics custom events. So if there's a way to see which custom events have previously been called for this session, that would also solve the problem.

Something like this would be ideal:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});
```

However, that is only for the clientId, not for the session ID.

Answer (score 0):

GA UA (analytics.js) doesn't surface session ids. GA UA calculates/generates them later on because of how complex the rules for them are.

GA4 (gtag.js) does generate a session id and stores it on the front-end since the rules for sessions are now way simpler. It stores it in a cookie that starts from _ga and then has your tracking code in it. Here is how it looks here, on this page on SO:

[image]

Finally, here is how you get the value from gtag (it's cleaner than parsing the cookie):

```js
gtag('get', 'G-WCZ03SZFCQ', 'session_id', (field) => console.log(field))
```

If you want to read more on gtag api, here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference).

Note that it wants a callback to get the field:

[image]

Not sure why Google decided to make the get function async just to get a cookie. Probably they just decided to follow the same pattern and some items to require async for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics does not provide a way to access the session ID directly. However, you can use the clientId to tie certain behavior to a user's session.

The clientId is a unique identifier that is generated by GA for each user. It is stored in the browser's cookies, and is used to identify a user across multiple sessions.

You can use the ga function to access the clientId as you mentioned in your example:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
  // use the clientId to tie certain behavior to a user's session
});
```

You can also use custom events to track different versions of the site, as you mentioned. You can then use the clientId to see which custom events have previously been called for a user's session.

It's worth noting that if you're using GA cookies with the same domain across different subdomains, you'll have to use the linker plugin to properly track the client ID across those subdomains.

```
ga('create', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['domain1.com', 'domain2.com']);
```

In summary, while GA does not offer a direct way to access the session ID, you can use the clientId and custom events to tie certain behavior to a user's session and track different version of the site.