# Google Analytics 4 Session id GTM variable

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, sessionid

Is it possible to get the Google Analytics 4 session id via the GTM variable? I need to send the value for offline conversion tracking.

Comment: see my response here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75101333/connect-data-to-a-google-analytics-session-in-javascript I covered GA4 in it.